# How do I reduce redirect chain with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I've been having some problem with solving the redirect chain of my website. I wanted my website to ultimately have only one version, which is **HTTPS + non-www + trailing slash**

When tested, below htaccess gave me 4 response with redirect chain out of 8 total variation tested (https, www/non-www,trailing slash, 2x2x2 = 8 variations).

The http://www. variation gave me a redirect chain with 3 redirects
http://www.  --> https://www. --> https://www. + trailing slash ---> https:// + trailing slash

Is there a way that I can make it no redirect chain or at least not more than 2?

Appreciate if someone could help me out! Thanks

```
# Force trailing slash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

# HTTPS forced by SG-Optimizer
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Was any of the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www\. [NC]      
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to force HTTPS//non-WWW and remove trailing slashes from files in **one redirect**. That's a bit demanding and require some sort of GOTO/SKIP logic in the .htaccess file. Try it like this with a fresh browser in incognito mode:

```
RewriteEngine on

## Check if not a directory and ends in /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
## If not a directory skip next RewriteRule
RewriteRule ^ - [S=2]

## Check if HTTPS and non-WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off

## This RewriteRule skipped if URI was a directory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

## This RewriteRule used if URI was a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

<sub>PS: I get the idea, but Google's Gary Illyes tweeted in 2016 "30x redirects don't lose PageRank anymore." So, even for SEO this is no longer a burning issue.</sub>

Comment: @JosephYap have you tried this? Does it work for you?